# How can I merge multiple parquet files with the same schema in java (only using input stream)?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, parquet

Is there any way in java to merge multiple parquet files without actually downloading the files on disk and just using their input streams?

Lets say for example these files are stored in google cloud blobs and we can access the input stream for each blob.